# Cannot login, password rejected, ubuntu 19

Tags: login, password

Installed Ubuntu 19 for the first time.
Worked fine, made an account but when I attempted to log in after closing my laptop Ubuntu didn't accept my password!?

I am a complete newb and it seems like a problem which I cannot find specifically for the latest Ubuntu 19.

It's my only OS so I am unable to use my laptop, a quick response would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 19,  main Ubuntu releases are *yy.mm* in format, though some specialist releases such as Ubuntu Core (for applicance/IoT devices) do use the *yy* format, but aren't intended for desktop/laptop use.  I would firstly check numlock, capslock - and were they in the same state as when password was made?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys, first thanks for the responses, appreciated.
I couldn't get to the grub menu however no matter how many times I tried pressing shift or esc, it frustrated me so much I just decided to reinstall Ubuntu so I could check the 'login automatically' box on install and temporarily fix the problem.
So I did that and when choosing the keyboard layout (French) and then entering the users name which used a US keyboard layout I noticed that maybe that had something to do with the password issue, which it did.
I now must enter my password remembering a US keyboard layout to be accurate.
Silly problem but hopefully it helps others in the future.
Just weird that even after choosing a French layout it still used US.
Thanks again guys.

Still don't know what to think about how I am unable to access this GRUB menu though..